# unable to execute post request with authorization header

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, http-post

I have an issue in angular 4 when I post a request API with Authorization header?

```
addPost(body): Observable<any>{
      const url = 'https://xxxxxx';

     return this.http.post(URL, body, this.options)
     .map((res:Response) => {
     this.data = res.json();
     })
}
```

token comes from firebase auth

```
afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
    .then(token => {
        this.headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
        });
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    });
this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
```

I call post by this

```
return this.getJob.addPost(body).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Response 403!!!

Request URL:https://us-central1-xxxxxx-prod.cloudfunctions.net/api/post
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 
Remote Address:216.58.198.51:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
access-control-allow-methods:GET, POST
access-control-allow-origin:

*cache-control:private

content-encoding:gzip

content-length:32

content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8

date:Tue, 08 Aug 2017 12:23:55 GMT

etag:W/"c-dAuDFQrdjS3hezqxDTNgW7AOlYk"

function-execution-id:d0la00v58w7p

server:Google Frontend

status:403

vary:Accept-Encoding

x-cloud-trace-context:d1b6ff9d729f7e250193a70aea16cac1;o=1

x-cloud-trace-context:d1b6ff9d729f7e250193a70aea16cac1

x-powered-by:Express

Request Headers

:authority:us-central1-xxxxxx-prod.cloudfunctions.net

:method:OPTIONS

:path:/api/post

:scheme:https

accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6
access-control-request-headers:authorization,content-type
access-control-request-method:POST
alexatoolbar-alx_ns_ph:AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.1
cache-control:no-cache
origin:http://localhost:8080
pragma:no-cache
referer:http://localhost:8080/extras/addjobpost
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36

Comment: A better way to solve this would be to create an interceptor that extends angular's http module

Comment: console option returns this
RequestOptions {method: null, headers: Headers, body: null, url: null, params: undefined…} 
is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below.

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'token');

let order = 'order=foobar';
console.log("data");

 return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers })
     .map((res: any) => res.json());
```

Comment: it's not login.
I use postman and token start 'Bearer '+token

Comment: It is an example for post request. No need to worry about that..Edited the answer please check.

Comment: console option returns this
RequestOptions {method: null, headers: Headers, body: null, url: null, params: undefined…} 
is it true?

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this would be to create a interceptor that extends the default http module

Create a `interceptor.ts`

```
import {
    Http,
    Request,
    RequestOptionsArgs,
    Response,
    RequestOptions,
    ConnectionBackend,
    Headers
}
    from '@angular/http';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {

    constructor(private backend: ConnectionBackend, private defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private router: Router) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.request(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.delete(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options === null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }

        if (options === undefined) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }

        let headers = new Headers();
        let key = 'auth.jwt.token';
        let item = localStorage.getItem(key) ? localStorage.getItem(key) : null;
        let parsedToken = JSON.parse(item);

        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + parsedToken.token);
        if(options.headers) {
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
          headers.append('accept', 'application/json');
        } else {
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        }
        //Clearing the headers and appending the token + content type every request.
        options.headers = new Headers();

        options.headers = headers;

        return options;
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {
            if (err.status === 401 && !err.endsWith(err.url, 'api/auth/login')) {
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return Observable.empty();
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Inside your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpInterceptor } from 'interceptor.ts';

export function httpInterceptorFactory(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router) {
  return new HttpInterceptor(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router);
}
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpModule, SharedModule.forRoot()],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [{
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
    }, SomeService, AnotherService, 
    {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: httpInterceptorFactory,
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]
    }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then just call `http` as per usual, for example `this._http.get().map()` and the interceptor will append the token for you.

EDIT:

Updated answer to include a basic `app.module.ts`

Comment: useFactory isn't defined

Comment: Updated my answer to include a whole app.module.ts, I thought you'd get the idea of how to do it by just telling you to add the provider...

Comment: console option returns this
RequestOptions {method: null, headers: Headers, body: null, url: null, params: undefined…} 
is it true?

Answer (score 0):

I replace header to params

```
getTokenHeader() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
    .then(token => {
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('tsid', `Bearer ${token}`);
        return params;
    });
}
```

and call getTokenHeader in this function

```
    addPost(body): Observable<any>{//
        // const url = 'https://us-central1-talentdraw-prod.cloudfunctions.net/api/post';
        let url = this.api.URL['main']+this.api.URL['afterAuth'];

        return new Observable(observer => {
            this.getTokenHeader()
            .then(tokenOptions => {
                // console.log(tokenOptions);

                return this.http.get(url, { 
                    search: tokenOptions
                    })
                    .map((res:Response) => {
                        // this.data = res.json().data;
                        observer.next(res);
                        observer.complete();
                    })
                    .subscribe((data) => {
                        observer.complete();
                    })
                })
                .catch(( error: any ) => {
                    observer.error(error);
                    observer.complete();
                });
        })
    }
```